# blogger to wordpress - memory limit

Tags: wordpress, memory, limit, blogger, migrate

I want to migrate a blog from blogger.com to WordPress site (shared hosting). I´ve tried import blog through blogger importer plugin, but always get error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 72 bytes) in
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/3/2/32351905-3603-4b37-8de0-792810784a45/katharine-fashionisbeautiful.com/web/wp-includes/SimplePie/Parser.php
>   on line 322

I was trying many options found on net (setting of php.ini, wp-confing.php, setting of maximum upload size on hosting...) but everytime I got this error. I asked my hosting provider for reason. He said memory limit in php.ini for shared hosting is default 256MB and can not be changed. Then I tried to split my XML file (it's not very large - 11,1MB) (i said: maybe will work) but I don't know how. I tried WRXsplit but always get an error. Can you help me? Does exists some other way how to get blogger content to a WordPress site?

Thank you very much.

have nice day

Michal

Comment: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

That worked! But I suggest to put it in your wp-config.php above the line: /* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Comment: THX but i find another reason - not "Blogger Importer" plugin but "Blogger Importer Extended" by Yuri Farina. So easy and i spend 5 horrible days :) Every tutorials navigate you to blogger importer like there doesnt exist another way.